# install wordpress locally on OS X without MAMP (permission error)

Tags: macos, apache, wordpress, permissions, local

I'm trying to install wordpress locally on a mac with the built in stuff (apache/php) without installing MAMP. basically I'm following this tutorial:

https://gist.github.com/1500117

after editing the httpd.conf file, and restarting apache, I get this error in the browser:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Any ideas?
I'm using Snow Leopard

Answer (score 1):

well it seams I found what caused the problem. 
the Sites folder, where I put the wordpress folder had permissions 750, after changing it to 751, now it works. 
is this a proper solution or I should keep digging?

Answer (score 0):

While there are a lot of variables to check here, the two biggest are the server root (make sure the case of all the path elements is correct) and the user permissions/owner of the WordPress files themselves.

All that said, why not use MAMP for this kind of situation?

Comment: the path I added is "/Users/myusername/Sites/wordpress"
and I changed the owner of the wordpress files to "_www", and added write permission to all. 

nothing against MAMP, I just thought if I already have all the components to set up the server and in theory it should work why not leave out installing another thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing http://your-host-name/index.php

If that fixes it, then your DirectoryIndex directive (in httpd.conf) needs to be changed to    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

If that does not fix it, type    tail -f /var/log/apache2/error_log at the console and look at the terminal screen while you hit http://your-host-name/index.php in your browser. It may tell you what the problem is. If not, paste the last few lines of the log file up here and I'll look at it for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I should break down into two scenarios:

1: mysql is running, web sharing is on, php is enabled in httpd.conf
I type localhost in the browser and I get "It works!"

2: all of the above is done, plus DocumentRoot and <Directory...> is 
changed to the path where my fresh copy of wordpress is (/Users/myusername/Sites/wordpress) and ownership of wordpress is changed to "_www", plus write permission added. 
after typing localhost to the browser I get "Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server."

I assume after this I still should get "It works!"

Comment: in the log I get: [Thu Apr 12 11:07:30 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (13)Permission denied: access to /favicon.ico denied, referer: http://localhost/